# How do I get around 'TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument,got 2' in line 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("Hello")
name = input("What is your name?")
age = int(input("What is your age?",name)) 
print("Thank you",name, "you have been registered an age of",int(age))
```

In line 3, I had gotten 'TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument,got 2'. I am a complete novice and I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: What would `input("What is your age?",name)` mean?

Comment: You can only give 1 argument to `input()` function. You have also given `name` as argument.

Comment: Input won't concat variables into strings  like print does. If you are trying to concat the name in the question you can do something like: `int(input(f"What is your age, {name}?"))`

Comment: Do you know what an `argument` is in this context?

Comment: No, not too much.

Comment: Just realised my mistake.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

As `input` takes only one argument, your code should look like

```py
print('Hello')
name = input('What is your name?')
age = int(input(f'What is your age {name}?')) 
print(f'Thank you {name}, you have been registered an age of {age}')
```

Comment: I would argue about line 3 - there should be no comma before `{name}` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of writing the name also while asking the age, then you should try this.

```
print("Hello")
name = input("What is your name?")
age = int(input("What is your age?"+name)) 
print("Thank you",name, "you have been registered an age of",int(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
age = int(input("What is your age " + name + "?"))
```

or

```py
age = int(input("What is your age?"))
```

Comment: no not really, just in case of non string name used by error. I think it's not a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for helping.

Comment: I think there was someone who put a string before the name.                                   
    age = int(input("What is your age " + (str)name + "?"))